# What happens after eleven kicks from the penalty mark?

Tags: rules, football, penalty-shot

On April, 20 2017) [Besiktas and Lyon](http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuropaleague/season=2017/matches/round=2000795/match=2019697/index.html) took eight (8) kicks from the penalty mark each.

What would have happened if the balance had kept up to the eleventh (11th) kicks?

Which player would have taken the twelvth (12th) kick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In penalty shootouts in association football, a format of sudden death is followed if after 5 penalty shots each, the scores are still tied. If the number exceeds 11* penalty kicks each without a winner, all players become eligible to take a second penalty kick. The order of penalty kick takers can be changed, but all 11* players must take a second kick before any player can take a third kick, if required.

From the [IFAB Laws of the Game, Section 3. Kicks From The Penalty Mark](http://theifab.com/laws/determining-the-outcome-of-a-match/chapters/kicks-from-the-penalty-mark)

> - If, after both teams have taken five kicks, the scores are level kicks continue until one team has scored a goal more than the other from the same number of kicks.
> - Each kick is taken by a different player and all eligible players must take a kick before any player can take a second kick.
> - The above principle continues for any subsequent sequence of kicks but a team may change the order of kickers.

Such an incident took place in the [quarter finals of the 2006 Africa Cup of Nations between Cameroon and Ivory Coast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Africa_Cup_of_Nations#Quarter-finals). Each of the first 11 penalty kicks were converted by both teams. Samuel Eto'o, who took the first penalty kick for Cameroon, took the twelfth spot kick and missed. Didier Drogba, who took the first penalty kick for Ivory Coast, took the twelfth spot kick and scored, thus winning the match.

[This article](http://www.rsssf.com/miscellaneous/penalties.html) lists the interesting records pertaining to penalty shootouts. Some interesting ones:

- In domestic high level competition, the record for most penalty kicks taken was set by [KK Palace and Civics in the first round of the 2004/05 Namibian Cup](http://www.rsssf.com/miscellaneous/penalties.html#nam05), with KK Palace winning 17-16 after 48 penalty kicks (24 kicks per team).
- The highest score in a penalty shootout was 20-19 set in the 1988/89 Argentine Championship match between Argentinos Juniors and Racing Club, with Argentinos Juniors winning after 44 penalty kicks (22 kicks per team).
- The record in domestic amateur football is 52 kicks.  It happened in the 5th tier of Czech football in 2016; Batov beat Frystak 21-20.  [See the video](http://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/row-zed/longest-penalty-shoot-out-history-8119371).

* ***Note:** In case one of the teams has less than 11 players on the pitch at the time of the penalty shootouts, either due to red cards or injuries, the other team must exclude as many players as required to equate the number of penalty kick takers. This is done to ensure that the team's 11th spot kick is not taken by the best player of the team with the sent off player, giving them an advantage against the weakest player of the team with a fuller squad. In such a scenario, the 11th penalty kick will be taken a player who has already taken one spot kick earlier.*

Comment: This answer is strong, but could be even stronger with a reference to the [Laws of the Game](http://theifab.com/laws).

Comment: Also, it would be stronger if the number 11 was disregarded when reciting the general principle, as in [Yosef's answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/16003/3526). 11 is only applicable here because both teams had 11 players left on the field at the end of the match. The general principle is that no eligible player takes a second kick until all kickers have had their first kick.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Laws of the game](http://static-3eb8.kxcdn.com/documents/60/Laws%20of%20the%20Game_16-17_Digital_Eng.pdf):

> - Each kick is taken by a different player and all eligible players must take a kick before any player can take a second kick.
>
> - The above principle continues for any subsequent sequence of kicks but a team may change the order of kickers.

So if it had gone past 11 they have to repeat kickers but the team is allowed to change the order of their 11 kickers.